# Unpivot grouped SQL Data

Tags: google-bigquery, pivot, transpose, unpivot

I have table [dataset] as following:

| Date | Person | Question | Answer | Answer Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic A Question 1 | Apple | Good |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic A Question 2 | Banana | Bad |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic A Question 3 |  |  |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic B Question 1 | Dog | Red |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic B Question 2 | Cat | Black |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Topic B Question 3 | Horse | Blue |

Seem illogical but I need to have in the following format:

| Date | Person | Topic A | Topic A Notes | Topic B | Topic B Notes |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022/04/10 | A | Apple, Banana | Good, Bad | Dog, Cat, Horse | Red, Black, Blue |

How do I achieve this? I have tried the following:

```
SELECT a.Date, 
       a.Person,
       topA.Answer AS Topic A,
       topA.Answer Notes AS Topic A Notes,
       topB.Answer AS Topic B,
       topB.Answer Notes AS Topic A Notes

FROM [Dataset] a
LEFT JOIN [Dataset] topA
    ON a.Date = topA.Date
    AND a.Person = topA.Person
    AND topA.Question LIKE 'Topic A%'
LEFT JOIN [Dataset] topB
    ON a.Date = topB.Date
    AND a.Person= topB.Person
    AND topB.Question LIKE 'Topic B%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try below:

```sql
WITH parsed_dataset AS (
  SELECT *,
         REGEXP_EXTRACT(Question, r'^Topic (\w+)') AS Topic,
         REGEXP_EXTRACT(Question, r'Question (\d+)$') AS Number
    FROM Dataset
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Date, Person, Topic,
         ARRAY_AGG(Answer IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Number) AS Answer,
         ARRAY_AGG(Answer_Notes IGNORE NULLS ORDER BY Number) AS Note
    FROM parsed_dataset
   GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
) PIVOT (
  ANY_VALUE(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', Answer), '[]')) Topic, 
  ANY_VALUE(TRIM(FORMAT('%t', Note), '[]')) Topic_Note FOR Topic IN ('A', 'B')
);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select * except(Question)
  from your_table, unnest([struct(
    regexp_extract(Question, r'^Topic (\w+)') as Topic,
    regexp_extract(Question, r'Question (\w+)') as QuestionNum 
  )])
)
pivot ( 
  string_agg(Answer, ', ' order by QuestionNum) as Topic,
  string_agg(Answer_Notes, ', ' order by QuestionNum) as Topic_Notes
  for Topic in ('A', 'B') 
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]